# Who are the new philosophers Nietzsche is referring to ?

Tags: nietzsche

From Beyond Good and Evil :

*"For that we have to await the advent of a new species of philosophers, ones whose taste and inclination are somehow different and the reverse of those hitherto—philosophers of the dangerous Perhaps in every sense.— And in all seriousness: I see such new philosophers coming up."*

Who are the new philosophers he refers to in the last line ?

Comment: Nietzsche himself ...

Comment: Nietzsche rendered the prose of the Enlightment into the poetry of himself; if he hasn't mentioned any names it will be hard to point to one though.

Comment: Nietzsche himself is the obvious choice. He would possibly have been proud of Hölderlin and his evolution of thought. But he most certainly did not know him much as a philosopher. Perhaps Camus would qualify, who he obviously could not know. But if there are not notes of himself on that, I fear the question is not answerable objectively or meaningful besides answering "Philosophers like him." :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Kant, had made that statement, I am sure you would have no problem answering your question.  Since Nietzsche is more "current," the obvious answer is, **future philosophers**.  Those philosophers coming after, or starting with, him!

Answer (score 0):

He was certainly seeing change in the world. To me it's obvious that he included himself in that sentence, and seeing great thinkers such as Dostoevsky and Mark Twain around, he could feel the time was ripe for that new kind of thought in "professional philosophy" too.